# Dynamic tooltip doesnot work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do like http://responsiweb.com/themes/preview/ace/1.3.3/calendar.html 
tooltip as it is having at the end of calendar..

My static code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-list" style="">
    <li class=""><a href="#"><i class="menu-icon fa fa-calendar"></i><span class="menu-text">
        Calendar <span class="badge badge-transparent tooltip-error" title="" data-html="true"
            data-original-title="2 Important Events <br/>
            2 Important Events <br />
            2 Important Events 2 Important Events2 Important Events 2 Important Events2 Important Events 2 Important Events2 Important Events 2 Important Events2 Important Events 2 Important Events2 Important Events 2 Important Events2 Important Events 2 Important Events2 Important Events 2 Important Events2 Important Events 2 Important Events2 Important Events 2 Important Events2 Important Events 2 Important Events">
            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-exclamation-triangle red bigger-130"></i></span></span>
    </a><b class="arrow"></b></li>
```

But when I make exactly like this using javascript like

```
jobinfo.push(document.createElement('span')); // IGNORE VARIABLE NAMES
            var jobinfo_i = document.createElement('i');
            jobinfo[j].setAttribute('class', 'badge badge-transparent tooltip-error pull-right');
            jobinfo_i.setAttribute('class', 'fa fa-info-circle');
            jobinfo[j].setAttribute('title', "2 Important Events fa fa-exclamation-triangle &#013; 2 Important Events fa fa-exclamation-triangle &#013;2 Important Events fa fa-exclamation-triangle &#013; 2 Important Events fa fa-exclamation-triangle &#013;");
            jobinfo[j].setAttribute('data-html', true);
            jobinfo[j].setAttribute('data-original-title', "2 Important Events fa-check ");
            jobinfo[j].setAttribute('style', 'position:static;padding:0px;');
```

then it doesnot show any tooltip..any suggestion plz..

as I have tried bootstrap tooltip also but it is not so responsive..if my button or li is down of page and I hover on it then it doesnot adjust tooltip size..

Comment: you better provide a fiddle or open console and see any errors occurred .